# How to fix 'missing FROM-clause entry for table ' error in metabase

Tags: sql, metabase

I'm trying to join three tables and I keep receiving error codes

```
select
  bor.bellhop_full_name,
  count(bor.order_id) as Moves,
  avg(orders.order_review_score) as Order_Rating
from _gospel.bellhop_order_relationship as bor
  join _gospel.orders on orders.order_id = bor.order_id
  join _gospel.incidents on orders.order_id = incidents.order_id
```

> error message: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table
>   "bellhop_order_relationship" Position: 664

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (I'm guessing postgres)? You are aggregating two columns in your SELECT clause but you don't have the the non-aggregated column contained in a GROUP BY (not sure if it's related to the error message, but that error may pop next depending on your RDBMS). Why join in `_gospel.incidents` if you never use it (also unrelated to the error)? Is there more to this SQL that you aren't sharing? If this is `postgres` then I'm guessing somewhere in some SQL you aren't sharing there is a reference to the table `bellhop_order_relationship` instead of its alias `bor`.

Comment: You are also missing `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the `group by`, I wonder if that solves the problem:

```
select b.bellhop_full_name,
       count(*) as Moves,
       avg(o.order_review_score) as Order_Rating
from _gospel.bellhop_order_relationship b join
     _gospel.orders o
     on o.order_id = b.order_id join
     _gospel.incidents i
     on o.order_id = i.order_id
group by b.bellhop_full_name;
```